# Strange error in xampp using include function

Tags: php, include, xampp, require

I have a strange error with this, i'm testing one soft in my localhost with xampp and in one part of the code need include class from another file, the path is correct and when file is included appear a strange error and all code inside the class of the file included is printed in the screen, and in the final line show the error of

`Fatal error: Class 'users' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\folder\index.php on line 81`

Most strange is that, this same code works perfectly in my online server, i'm not sure if is some bad configuration in my xampp, i have tried with:

`require` `require_once` `include` `include_once`

and all is the same.

Someone have an idea?

Comment: Need to see some codes in order to help further. :-)

Comment: @xlordt thanks for your help, i have found the error, the problem was that the file had wrong `<?php` in the start, anyway after this it throw another smarty error, i decided continue editing online because all code is large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error, the problem was that the file had wrong `<?php` in the start.